# Using a string vs an id as a foreign key in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, foreign-keys, schema, database, nosql

I have a collection `users` whose documents will belong to a `company` (and each company can have many `users`). Because I set a unique index on the company name, can I use the name as the foreign key inside the `user` document, or is it recommended to use the id instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If name is unique and is guaranteed to never change, then you can use it, no problem. Although there were cases in my practice when names turned out to be not-so-unique and not-so-immutable (damn requirement changes). So, just to be extra safe, use the id.